# Working with multi tier .json files/accessing lower tier data

Tags: c#, json

When working with multi-tier .json files, I have a hard time understanding how to work with data from lower tiers after deserialization. In this instance, I can do with ignoring null values, or making them accessible.

I have attempted using `[JsonProperty("stepdown", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` to ignore the property but that has not worked so far.

heres a bit of code for those who would prefer to see it. the last 2 props are what im talking about.

***JSON CLASS***

```
public partial class Preset
{
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("f_n")]
    public double? FN { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("f_z")]
    public double? FZ { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("guid")]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("n")]
    public double N { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("n_ramp")]
    public double? NRamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tool-coolant")]
    public string ToolCoolant { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("use-stepdown")]
    public bool UseStepdown { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("use-stepover")]
    public bool UseStepover { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_c")]
    public double VC { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_f")]
    public double? VF { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_f_leadIn")]
    public double? VFLeadIn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_f_leadOut")]
    public double VFLeadOut { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_f_plunge")]
    public double VFPlunge { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_f_ramp")]
    public double VFRamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("v_f_retract")]
    public double VFRetract { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stepdown", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public double Stepdown { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stepover", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public double Stepover { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that changing `public double Stepdown { get; set; }` to `public double? Stepdown { get; set; }` got me passed this issue.

**Original Code**
[JsonProperty("stepdown", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public double Stepdown { get; set; }

```
[JsonProperty("stepover", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public double Stepover { get; set; }
```

**Modified Code**

```
 [JsonProperty("stepdown", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public double? Stepdown { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("stepover", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public double? Stepover { get; set; }
```

Comment: But what was the result, did you get any error trying to serialize?

Comment: No this code worked for me. I have not ever really edited my questions and responses here on stackoverflow so I did not know if I should write my edits in past tense, or update to current status. Either way in this instance, this solution worked at the time of the original writing, and still currently works in my code!